# Set marginleft to an imageview doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:background="@drawable/roundededges"                        
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:id="@+id/articleBoxLayout">
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="30sp"               
       android:text="Test Test Title"
       android:typeface="sans"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:singleLine="true" 
       android:paddingRight="4dip"
       android:textSize="20sp"  
       android:textColor="#C98E04"
       android:textStyle="bold"                         
       android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/articleImage"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/articleTitle"
    android:marginBottom="18dip"
    android:marginLeft="18dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/aaa" />

<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/articleSubTitle"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/articleImage" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/articleTitle"
       android:gravity="right"           
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"        
       android:text="blablablabla"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:textSize="10sp"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"                
       android:clickable="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For some reason the marginLeft doesn't affect the ImageView position.

The ImageView stays stick to the left(aligned left).

What can be the problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `android:layout_marginLeft` instead of `android:marginLeft`

so the correct xml for ImageView should be:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/articleImage"
android:layout_width="65dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:layout_below="@+id/articleTitle"
android:layout_marginLeft="18dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dip"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/aaa" />
```

Answer (score 1):

just put this code to make your android imageview with margin in any position

```
android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
```

for more detail about android layout browse here http://grabcodes.blogspot.in/